# Count the number of customers who have > 10 transactions, excluding returns?

Tags: sql-server

My table 'Transactions' has the following columns :

- CustID --- a unique CustomerID
- transactionID -- a unique TransactionID
- Qty --- Quantity. Values can be positive or negative. Positive values means an order was made. Negative value means the order was returned.
- total_amt --- Total_amount, cost of the total order. Value is calculated by multiplying Qty by the cost of the product.

I ran the following query and got some output, but since I don't have the expected output with me.Therefore, I want someone to help me to confirm if this code will always work and suggest edits if it doesn't.

```
select cust_id, COUNT(cust_id) AS Count_of_Transactions
from Transactions
where Qty >= 0
group by cust_id
having COUNT(cust_id) > 10
```

I don't have the expected output.

Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I'd count on TransactionId, but other than that, looks fine.

Comment: I have to ask...why is TransactionID in the customers table? Seems to me you need to have at a bare minimum two tables here and probably at least three.

Comment: @steenbergh since this is all one table why does it matter which column to count? I would just count(*) to get the number of rows.

Comment: For me, your script looks fine the only point is here it will output list the customer not the count of it

Comment: Please share your output. because the above query is correct. I also used same query.

Comment: @SeanLange I'd use TransactionID because it better describes what the query does: counting transaction ID's.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the expected output, I think what you have is right.  If you want to see the total amount summed up, you would just need to add one more column to your query:

```
SELECT cust_id, 
    SUM(total_amt) AS Total_Amount_of_Transactions, 
    COUNT(cust_id) AS Count_of_Transactions
FROM Transactions
WHERE Qty >= 0
GROUP BY cust_id
HAVING COUNT(cust_id) > 10
```